# R: piping (%>%) not working with round(). Ex: 136/13.00 %>% round() = 10.46154

Tags: r, rounding, piping

why does `136/13.00 %>% round()` return 10? The same input without the piper returns the correct value

```
136/13.00 %>% round()
[1] 10.46154
> round(136/13.00)
[1] 10
10.46154 %>% round()
[1] 10
```

Comment: Try `136 %>% '/'(13) %>% round`

Comment: Or explicitly specify the order of operations, like `(136/13.00) %>% round()`

Comment: I see in the answers bellow that this is because %>% takes precedence over /. Is that a bug or a feature though?  I don´t see any logic for piping to have precedence over anything going before it. At least that is not what people using the tidyverse have in mind when they think about piping

Answer (score 5):

Looks like operator precedence

```
(136/13) %>% 
          round
#[1] 10
```

We can also make it a bit more chainy

```
136 %>%
     `/`(13) %>%
     round
#[1] 10
```

Comment: Yes.  13 is being rounded prior to dividing 136.  If I were to chain this, I would use `magrittr`s division function, i.e. `136 %>% divide_by(13) %>% round()`

Comment: is this a feature or a bug (seem my comment to the question)?

Comment: @LucasMation As it is mentioned, the operator precedence is something we need to check.

Answer (score 4):

Because of  [operator precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html). `%any%` operators have higher precedence than, for example, `/`. So round is first applied to 13 (changing nothing), then 136 is divided by 13.